# USB to PCMCIA adapter?

Tags: usb, pcmcia

I have [PCMCIA CAN card](http://www.vector.com/vi_cancardxl_en.html) I need to use with a laptop that does not have a PCMCIA slot. Is there a USB solution for this? Most things on Google reveal PCMCIA to USB (a PC card with USB ports). I did see [this](http://www.quatech.com/catalog/drives_pcmcia.php), but it's only for 3G wireless internet cards. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked for similar device and found some listed here [Adapters](http://www.synchrotech.com/products/card-rw_00.html).  One issue we have found is that some cards have issue with the adapter and do not read properly.  Mostly older 16 bit cards not cardbus